# How to convert average horse power?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, power

My question is

> " A locomotive engine draws a load $m$ pounds up an inclined plane making angle  $a$   with horizontal, the coefficient of friction being  $k$ . If  starting from rest and moving with uniform acceleration,  it acquired a velocity of $v$ **ft/sec** in $t$ **seconds** , find the average Horse Power at which the engine has worked  ".

In the question   author calculate Average velocity
=( v+0)/2  . Then he calculate  Avereg H.P ( horse power) =
P×V/2g where P be the force   applied by the engine along the plane to pull the partical  . He resolved  mgsina + kR   along the plane  where R   is the normal reaction  and make equation of motion     mf = P-mgsina -kR. My problem is  in the calculation of  Average H.P why he divide it  by g . 
Also he use vertically downward  force  as mg  . I want to ask if m is in pound then what is unit of mg ? 
Please help me . This subject is not of my field . Only because it seems most interesting to me that is why I learn it . Please help

Comment: What is "P"? How does friction ("k") enter the author's calculation?

Comment: Sorry , I edit it sir . You can check it now

Comment: Without following the calculations, could it be because "pound" can be both a unit of mass and a unit of force (i.e. mass times g)?

Comment: Sir , are you saying here P= mass ×g this implies P/g = mass  of the body on which P applied?

Comment: I am not making any claim (and am still wondering why the result would be independent of friction and the angle).   Where it says "engine draws a load m pounds" is the $m$ a mass or a force/weight?

Comment: Average over time, over distance or over speed? An "average" can be defined many ways.

Comment: I suggest you change the title to something like "Confused about US units in calculating horsepower." Your title asks to find average power, but the question is about the use of $g$ as a divisor in the answer.

Comment: @Gilll ... It would be better if you give a picture of that copy ... And as unit of $mg$ , I can imagine it's **ft-poundel** ...